# Create a touch file on Unix

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and had a requirement to create a zero byte/tag/touch file on Unix server using R.

Is it possible to create a file on Unix using R?

Comment: I would start here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/files.html

Comment: Also read `?system2` or `?system` and this is the comman you should use `try(system("touch file", intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE))`

Answer (score 7):

You can create an empty data frame and write that to disk:

```
x <- data.frame()
write.table(x, file='empty', col.names=FALSE)
```

Result:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 matt matt    0 May 28 20:29 empty
```